# How to use the hasNext multiple times

Tags: java.util.scanner

So I am working on a program that will use Scanner to read through a text file and count the number of words, sentences, etc. I have code that works, but only to some degree and it is confusing me greatly. I have these two classes,

```
public void sentences()
{
    while(text.hasNext())
    {
       // code to check for and count sentence ends 
    }
}

public void words()
{
    while(text.hasNext())
    {
       // code to count for words
    }
}
```

The confusing (to me) part is when I run both of these methods they work. However, (the order doesn't matter) the second one will not work. So if I were to write

```
w.words();
w.sentences();
```

the sentences method will do nothing and give me a value of 0. I have done some testing with system.out.println() and the *sentences* method will get called, but it will skip over the loop. So I feel like there something to do with the hasNext() method. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The loop in `words` finishes when `hasNext` returns false. Unless you do something before the call to `sentences` it will still return false there, and never enter the loop.